# Ubuntu does no longer find host from DNS-Server after a while

Tags: networking, server, dns

Since a few days I have a Raspberry Pi with dnsmasq setup as DNS Server on 192.168.1.2 in my LAN. It helps other computers to find the server by name ... and it works great, except for my Ubuntu 18.04 Laptop which seems to somehow "forget" the server.

When the laptop is started, at first everything works fine. From the command line nslookup server.lan, host server.lan, ping server.lan all give correct results and opening a webpage on the server works fine.

```
xeros@laptop:~ $ nslookup server.lan
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   server.lan
Address: 192.168.1.3
```

However after a while it stops working. Opening the Website from the server says it can not be found and nslookup suddenly fails:

```
xeros@laptop:~ $ nslookup server.lan
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find server.lan: NXDOMAIN
```

The DNS-Server is working though. No problems on my smartphone or any other device. Also if I specify the DNS-Server, the correct answer is returned on my Ubuntu laptop:

```
xeros@laptop:~ $ nslookup server.lan 192.168.1.2
Server:     192.168.1.2
Address:    192.168.1.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   server.lan
Address: 192.168.1.3
```

If I restart the laptop, things work fine again.

I have no clue why it fails after a while. Anybody has an idea what could be going wrong?

---

Edited for additional information as requested (executed on the RPi DNS-Server):

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 47 Dec  8 16:43 /etc/resolv.conf
```

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
#Domains=
#LLMNR=yes
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=udp
```

And the same for the laptop:

```
xeros@laptop:~$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Mai  1  2018 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

```
xeros@laptop:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

```
xeros@laptop:~$ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

Comment: Adjust as necessary: `sudo journalctl --since="-10 minutes"` to see the logs. Also `sudo journalctl $(type -p dnsmasq)` will be of interest.

Comment: You only have dnsmasq running on the RPi, correct? On the RPi, show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema The RPi is running dnsmasq and an apache webserver. I have added the requested outputs to the question. Is there any reason to believe the setup on the raspberry DNS-Server is wrong? Other devices except the ubuntu laptop work fine. The RPi is running Raspbian, if that matters.

Comment: The RPi should have `#DNSStubListener=udp` changed to `DNSStubListener=no`. Show me the same info for the Ubuntu laptop. Is dnsmasq installed there? Is Raspbian based on Ubuntu?

Comment: I know this is not a direct answer to your question, but I have always had some weird issue or another with systemd-resolvd. Normally one of the first things I do is revert to the NetworkManager and my issues go away

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the configuration on the RPi. Do I need to restart something to have an effect? I also added the output from my Ubuntu Laptop for the same commands. The RPi is using Raspbian 9.11 based on Debian Stretch, not based on Ubuntu. Dnsmasq seems to be installed on the Ubuntu laptop, possibly pre-installed with 18.04?

Comment: In both cases, is it `dnsmasq` or `dnsmasq-base`? See `dpkg -l dnsmasq*`.

Comment: In both cases, assure that `host -v www.ebay.com` works after any mods/reboots.

Comment: @heynnema On the RPi it's dnsmasq (installed by myself), on the Ubuntu laptop it's dnsmasq-base

Comment: I put together a tentative potential answer. Give it a try and report back.

Comment: @heynnema I just wanted to let you know that the problem has not occurred anymore in the last 3 days. Before it happened every day. The only change applied was changing DNSStubListener=no and I have even undone this to see whether it was the cause of the problem. So, unsure why it seems to work now. I have not tested your answer yet, but will definitely do if the problem occurs again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on the Ubuntu laptop... this is clipped from one of my other answers here on AU...

report back...

---

We need to check if your DNS servers (dnsmasq) have a problem with the `options edns0` in /etc/resolv.conf.

/etc/resolv.conf is a symlink that goes to one of three places. Do a:

`ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` # note the original symlink setting

`sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf` # note the current file contents

`sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf` # remove the symlink

---

`sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # new symlink

`sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf` # note the current file contents

retest DNS using:

`host -v www.booking.com | grep -i received` # use a different web site every time

`sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf` # remove the symlink

---

Depending on the results, you can also try this symlink:

`sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # a different symlink

`sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf` # note the current file contents

retest DNS using:

`host -v www.booking.com | grep -i received` # use a different web site every time

`sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf` # remove the symlink

---

If one symlink works better than the other, keep it for now. If none work better, set it back to original:

`sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # reset to original symlink

Comment: Today the problem occurred once again and I have tried the above. The second symlink does not work, since /etc/resolv.conf does not exist on my system. If I change to the last solution, the internal server is correctly resolved and everything works. If I change back to the original version, nslookup server.lan fails once again. I have once again changed to the last configuration and hope it will work. It seems strange though that Ubuntu can't resolve the name in its standard configuration?